# C - reading from stdin BUFSIZE characters at a time

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, unix

I'm writing a small sockets program (GNU libc). I have a loop which asks user for input (e.g. "MSG> "). When the user presses enter the message is sent (currently to a server on localhost).

Anyway, I want to read from stdin into a char buffer[256]. I'm currently using fgets() which doesn't do what I want. I'm not sure how write the code such that I ask the user and then get data 256 -1 bytes at a time so that I can send a c-string of 1000 bytes via several strings of 256 bytes.

EDIT: Add code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char msg[BUFSIZE];
  size_t msgLen;

  msgLen = strlen(fgets(msg, BUFSIZE, stdin));
  puts(msg);

  // This simply checks whether we managed to fill the buffer and tries to get
  // more input
  while (msgLen == (BUFSIZE - 1))
    {
      memset (msg, '\0', BUFSIZE);
      fread(msg, BUFSIZE, 1, stdin);
      msg[BUFSIZE - 1] = '\0';
      msgLen = strlen(msg);
      puts(msg);
      if (msgLen < (BUFSIZE - 1))
    break;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't see why. The question is perfectly clear already, and has been answered correctly several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing a loop to ensure 1000 bytes are recieved, right? The loop should indicate that it's counting up to 1000, for the sake of legibility. Keep track of the number of bytes you read (using the += operator), and use that number in the loop condition.

You seem to assume that `fread` will read 255 bytes, but this is under the invalid assumption that 255 bytes are available. When less than 255 bytes are read, this doesn't necessarily indicate an error; keep reading! When the return value of `fread` is less than zero, then you should be worried. Make sure you handle those situations.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the `read` function for buffered input. It takes an open file descriptor (STDIN_FILENO for stdin), a pointer to a buffer (`char *`) and the count of bytes to read. See the manual [entry](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) for more details.

Comment: Using read in substitution of fread seems to introduce unnecessary complexity rather than solving the problem. There is no guarantee that read will null terminate the output suitable for strlen.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, stdin);
```

Comment: The problem is that if the user enters 1000 characters I want the code to silently read 255, then the next 255 char, then the next without asking the user for input again and again.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is - just run it in a loop - and check the return value. You may want to swap the `sizeof(buffer)` and `1` for that to work well, as fread returns how many items was successfully read - the first of the sizes is the size of each item, the second is the number of items you want to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `fgets()`, you're using the standard IO library.  You're going to want to use `fread()` then (instead of, say, `read()`, which uses a file descriptor), to specify the number of bytes to read.  See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/